# How to make a dialog box in android returning a value (boolean)

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am making an application in which i need to display dialog box many times,I do not want to write code of dialog box again and again,so how should I make a common dialog box so that i can perform different functions on selection of yes or no at different places. please help,I tried a lot but not got the solution.

Comment: You can create a generic function for showing alert dialog box. Consider defining different functions to take different types of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method like:

```
public Dialog showDialog(String title, String msg, final Activity activity) {

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(msg);
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();

                    activity.finish();

            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();

        return alertDialog;

    }
```

And wherever you want to make dialog just call `showDialog("Title","your message",Acitivity);`

Answer (score 0):

Declare dialog box as public

```
        public Dialog dialog_box;
```

Initialize it.... in oncreate...

```
    dialog_box = new Dialog(HSMPDFViewer.this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
    dialog_box.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog_box.setCancelable(true);
```

Make a function for it...
and use it...

```
     /**
 * Alert Dialog 
 */
public void AlertDialogMessage() {
    dialog_text.setText("Problem in loading ..");
    dialog_btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog_box.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog_box.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a class extended from Dialog/AlertDialog or whatever you want. Then you can implement some functionality of your custom Dialog box. You can make yesPerformed() and noPerformed() methods which ones you can simply **override** when you need to use your custom DialogBox.

Comment: If I want to call dialog at many different place,the how sholud i use its yesPerformed() or noPerformed() for different functionalities ??

Comment: When you extends your class from the Dialog or any other class u get all the functionality of the extended class. So what you can do with the original Dialog class u can do as well with your custom one.

Answer (score 0):

**I am just pasting my ready made code here as i did with my projects. Please modify different tags accordingly or ask me for further help!**

- The Following dialog can be made backward compatible to 1.6 using android v4 support library
- Dialog will not dismiss itself on device rotation.

This is how your dialog will looks like:
[image]

**Step 1: Create a new class with the name `ConfirmationDialog` and past the following code in it.**

```
public class ConfirmationDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private Handler mHandler;
private Bundle mBundle;
private String messageToShow;
private String dialogTitle;

public ConfirmationDialog(Handler mHandler, String dialogTitle,
        String messageToShow) {
    this.mHandler = mHandler;
    mBundle = new Bundle();
    this.messageToShow = messageToShow;
    this.dialogTitle = dialogTitle;
    Log.i(MyConstants.LOG_TAG,
            "------------CONSTRUCTOR EXECUTED------------");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    Log.i(MyConstants.LOG_TAG, "------------ONCREATE EXECUTED------------");
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(dialogTitle);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_alerts_and_states_warning);
    builder.setMessage(messageToShow);
    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok),
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mBundle.clear();
                    mBundle.putInt(MyConstants.CONFIRM_NOTE_DELETE_TAG,
                            MyConstants.DIALOG_OK);
                    Message m = new Message();
                    m.setData(mBundle);
                    mHandler.sendMessage(m);
                }
            });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            mBundle.clear();
            mBundle.putInt(MyConstants.CONFIRM_NOTE_DELETE_TAG,
                    MyConstants.DIALOG_CANCEL);
            Message m = new Message();
            m.setData(mBundle);
            mHandler.sendMessage(m);
        }
    });
    Dialog theDialog = builder.create();
    theDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    return theDialog;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance()) {
        getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
    }
}
```

**Then past the following code in the fragment where you want to show the dialog:**

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message m) {
        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
        mBundle = m.getData();
        Log.i(MyConstants.LOG_TAG, "Got the data returned by the Dialog!");

        int dialogOkCancel = MyConstants.DIALOG_CANCEL;
        if (!mBundle.isEmpty())
            dialogOkCancel = mBundle.getInt(
                    MyConstants.CONFIRM_NOTE_DELETE_TAG,
                    MyConstants.DIALOG_CANCEL);
        if (dialogOkCancel == MyConstants.DIALOG_OK) {
            Log.i(MyConstants.LOG_TAG, "Ok selected");              
        } else if (dialogOkCancel == MyConstants.DIALOG_CANCEL) {
            Log.i(MyConstants.LOG_TAG, "Cancel selected");
        }
    } // end handleMessage
};
```

**Step 3: Then execute this code when you want to show the dialog:**

```
ConfirmationDialog mConfirmationDialog = new ConfirmationDialog(
                        mHandler, "Delete Routine Task",
                        "Are you sure to delete Routine Task?");
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(mConfirmationDialog,
                        MyConstants.CONFIRM_NOTE_DELETE_TAG);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: this code is too big,I want a smaller way to do this, can't we use any shorter code instead of code you given in step two,I can't write code which you have given in 2nd step many times..it is too big to write many times

Comment: You dont have to write it. Just coply/past put your logic for Ok in `if (dialogOkCancel == MyConstants.DIALOG_OK) {}` condition for Cancel in `else if (dialogOkCancel == MyConstants.DIALOG_CANCEL) {}`.

Answer (score -1):

In order to avoid  code  rewriting for  Dialogues,I created a custom class  which  can be used  from any UI activity.

Create a customDialog class  as below and call from any activity by   CustomDialog.ShowErrorDialog(errormsg,myActivity.this);

or by

CustomDialog.ShowErrorDialogNRedirect(errormsg,myActivity.this,redirectActivityClass);

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;


/*****  
 * 
 *    This is CustomDialog class which is used commonly  in all the UI Activity .
 *  1)ShowErrorDialog function  is called from any activity by: 
 *  --> CustomDialog.ShowErrorDialog(errormsg,myActivity.this);
 *  
 *  This Dialogue shows  error msg only.
 *  
 *  
 *  2)ShowErrorDialogNRedirect function  is called from any activity by: 
 *  --> CustomDialog.ShowErrorDialogNRedirect(errormsg,myActivity.this,redirectActivityClass); 
 *   This Dialogue shows  error msg and redirects from one UI Activity to another Activity.
 *  
 * @author Jerry Abraham Varghese 
 * @license  WTFPL (do whatever you want with this, nobody cares)
 */     


public class CustomDialog  {

    // (1) Show  Error  Dialog
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void ShowErrorDialog(String errormsg ,final Activity activity)
 {
     AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();          
        // Setting Dialog Title
alertDialog.setTitle("Alert ");         
// Setting Dialog Message
alertDialog.setMessage(errormsg);           
// Setting Icon to Dialog
//alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);         
// Setting OK Button            
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
 // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
// Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
});         
// Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show(); 
 }

 // (2) Show  Error  Dialog &  Redirect After Showing the Dialogue
 @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "rawtypes" })
 public static void ShowErrorDialogNRedirect(String errormsg,final Activity activity,final Class nextRedirectActivityClass) {        
     AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();  
     // Setting Dialog Title
 alertDialog.setTitle(" "); 
 // Setting Dialog Message
 alertDialog.setMessage(errormsg);  
 // Setting Icon to Dialog
 alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.companylogo);   
 //On touch outside does not allow anything by setting "setCanceledOnTouchOutside" to false
 alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
 //In order to avoid the back pressed button not  to work when Dialog is open below code:
 alertDialog.setCancelable(false);   
 // Setting OK Button   
 alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
 // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
     Intent nextActivity= new Intent(activity,nextRedirectActivityClass);
     activity.startActivity(nextActivity);
     }
});     
// Showing Alert Message
alertDialog.show();  
 }//End function of ShowErrorDialog()   


}
```